# in_array and isset give different results?

Tags: php, arrays

I've got this json file, for instance, where i have some table metadata for my user.

```
{
    "id": {
        "index": ["primary", "auto_increment"],
        "unsigned": true,
        "type": "integer"
    },
    "nick": {
        "index": ["unique"],
        "type": "varchar",
        "minLength": 4,
        "maxLength": 10
    },
    "pw": {
        "type": "varchar",
        "minLength": 4,
        "maxLength": 10
    }
}
```

i check if a field is an index and what type of index it is.

---

if i do the check this way **within a foreach**

```
if (isset($value["index"]) && (in_array("primary", $value["index"]) || in_array("unique", $value["index"]))) {
    $arr[] = $key;
}
```

i get this result, as expected

```
Array
    (
        [0] => id
        [1] => nick
    )
```

---

but if i do it this way **within a foreach**

```
if (in_array("index", $value) && (in_array("primary", $value["index"]) || in_array("unique", $value["index"]))) {
    $arr[] = $key;
}
```

i get this result...

```
Array
    (
        [0] => id
    )
```

---

this is a little bit creepy. does anyone know why? i don't get it. in my opinion the *in_array-sample* must do the same as the *isset-sample*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in_array` does not check keys, it checks values. The `isset` method works fine and is fast, or you could

```
if (array_key_exists("index", $value) && (in_array("primary", $value["index"]) || in_array("unique", $value["index"]))) {
    $arr[] = $key;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
in_array("index", $value)
```

in_array has a third parameter for checking also types, and to not do loose comparisons. And as your second array has the entry `"unsigned": true` and `"index" == true` is true.

Use:

```
in_array("index", $value, true);
```

and you won't see any result. Because there's no value which is `"index"`.

So, use `array_key_exists` or the `isset` check, but not `in_array` which only checks for values.